# ATI driver in Fedora Linux 11

Tags: linux, drivers, amd-radeon

I recently built a PC with an ATI Radeon HD 5750. I have installed Fedora 11 and installed the device driver for the Radeon 5700 series proprietary drivers. I wanted to see if there is graphics hardware acceleration. I typed in glxinfo at the terminal and I got:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  135 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  14
Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

I don't know how to fix this. I tried to go to the ATI Catalyst Control Center; that worked, but the ATI Catalyst Control Center (Administrator) doesn't work. If anyone knows how to fix this problem then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

ATI Linux support sucks.  You'll save yourself a lot of headaches by replacing it with an NVIDIA card if you plan to use Linux more heavily.

That being said, these type of errors are usually due to a bug in the ATI installer on a 64-bit system (which you may have?), which tries to get the system to load a 32-bit driver instead of the 64-bit one.  If that's the case in your situation, you'll need to do this (as root or sudo):

```
mv /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so /usr/lib/dri/original-fglrx_dri.so
ln -s /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so
```

Then do:

```
aticonfig --initial
```

If that doesn't work, you can change it back:

```
mv /usr/lib/dri/original-fglrx_dri.so /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so
```

Comment: Agreed and 100% right with the crappy support. ATI driver is the worst on every platform, no need for further explanation I guess.